# Telegram.Bot: Mesage.From - есть, а где Mesage.To?

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Уважаемые господа,

собственно, почти весь вопрос поместился в заголовок.

Не могу понять объектную модель сообщения в библиотеке [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot).

В сообщениии есть поле `From`, но я не вижу поля `To`. В то же время, логически когда я пишу сообщение - я ведь его *кому то* адресую? Откуда можно получить эту инфу?

Вот как выглядит это в коде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не уверен, как тут, но From - это данные юзера, а не бота.

Comment: Если я напишу сообщение боту, то в поле From будетнаписано, что это я его написал. я - в смысле, я как пользователь телеграмм. А вот как боту (бот получает написанные ему сообщения, ведь так?) понять, что это ему написали и сообщение? Логичный ответ "потому, что он его получил!". Но получить сообющение он может не толькопотому, что ему написали, но и потом, например, что он входит в группу, и получает все сообщения, написанные "для группы"

Comment: Бот просто получает апдейды от телеграмма где есть обьект месседж (ну или колбек) и инфо о юзере, который это написал, ну и markup

Comment: А как мне понять, боту это сообщение адресовано, или в группу? Бот получает все сообщения, посылаемые группе. Мне это сильно мешает, я бы хотел чтобы "вот боту написали - реагируй, а не боту - сиди, молчи"

Comment: я хз как в шарпе, потому скажу как в питоне. Есть возможность проверки, когда юзер жмет на Ответить и происходит цитирование бота, и можно проверить есть ли у обьекта `Message` поле `reply_to_message` и если да, то тыры-пыры

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1XoFtOu пример

Comment: А что значит "боту это сообщение адресовано, или в группу" ? Вы имеете ввиду был ли упомянут бот в сообщении? Или же написали не через групповой чат, а в "личный" чат с ботом? В групповых чатах в объекте `message.chat`  есть `id` и он имеет отрицательное значение. В личном чате с ботом `id` положительное значение. Если упоминание бота в группе, то ручками фильтры писать..

Comment: @Rudi - большое спасибо, Ваше замечание позволило решить вопрос - то есть, знак числа message.chat.id и есть тот признак, который позволяет отличить сообщения, отправленные боту, от сообщений, отпарвленных в групповой чат. Может быть, у Вас есть возможность оформить это как ответ? я бы его принял...

Comment: @S.H. Я очень рад, если это сэкономило ваше время. Спасибо за предложение, возможно, когда-то у меня будет вопрос, в котором вы, сможете подсказать.. Вашего "спасибо" более чем достаточно)